# Accessing existing json object from an onClickListerner

Tags: android, json

In my `onCreate` I read a json string from a file into the string myData. Then load it into a `JSONObject allTheArray`

In my `onCreate` I have a `button_saveData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()` etc.

I want this to update the values in the `JSONObject` and then write to the local file again.

If I create a new `JSONObject myNewData` within the `onClickListener` and use

```
myNewData.put(name,value)
```

this works.

But if  I try to do this I cannot access the `JSONObject allTheArray` to use `allTheArray.put(name,value)` within the `onClickListener`.

**Question**: How do I define the original `JSONObject allTheArray` in `onCreate` so that it is accessible in the `onClickListener`

Pseudo Code :

```
protected Void onCreate(etc){
    String myData = readFromFile(this,data);
    JSONObject allTheArray = null;
    allTheArray = new JSONObject(myData);
    String value_id = allTheArray.getString("id");        
    text_id.setText(value_id);
}

onClickListener {
    it is in here I want to update allTheArray
    allTheArray.put(name,value);(I cannot access allTheArray here)
    then save 
}
```

So Question again: How do I make the JSONObject useable within the onClickListener when it has been defined in onCreate.

Comment: Though I had put this in the title but I am developing in Android using Android Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Either** make `allTheArray` to **global**

```
JSONObject allTheArray = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String myData = readFromFile(this, data);
    allTheArray = new JSONObject(myData);

    ....
}
```

**Or** mark it as `final`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String myData = readFromFile(this, data);
    final JSONObject allTheArray = new JSONObject(myData);

    ...

}
```

Comment: Thank you I will go away and try this...my head is spinning at the mo!

Comment: I have done what you say. final JSONObject allTheArray = new JSONObject(myData); I had to put a try and catch around the declarations but when I try to use allTheArray in  onClickListener I get an error saying it cannot resolve the symbol. Question: Please could you advise on solution.

Comment: OK I think I have found a solution in that I have defined allTheArray as a Global outside onCreate. I am now making progress, Thank you

Comment: @uberphoebe, Please accept the answer and press upvote. Thanks